# Hi what does #include <std_msgs/String.h> mean?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! i have general knowledge with c and c++ but quite new to ros.
I know #include includes libraries and headers such as #include <ros.h> etc.
But i dont get what #include <std_msgs/String.h> means, im guessing we are importing Sting.h library/header from std_msgs library? Somewhat like in python we use from ___ import ___. i dont even know what std_msgs is. I did my fair share of digging online but couldn't find any satisfactory answers. Also i have never seen a '/' inbetween an include before.
Thanks for whoever has read this. And thanks in advance to whoever replied. This is my first ever question in this page, dont know what to expect.
I got this question when i was doing the ros-arduino tutorials. The hello world one.  rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello World

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399738/hi-what-does-#include-%3Cstd_msgs/string.h%3E-mean?/) by [sajid1122](https://answers.ros.org/users/103351/sajid1122/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2022-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @sajid1122, so the line `#include "std_msgs/String.h` includes the std_msgs/String message, which resides in the std_msgs ros package. This is a header that is generated automatically from the `String.msg` file in that package. This is the way how ros works. If you want to understand this more deeply, you can refer these links - http://wiki.ros.org/std_msgs. This is the `std_msgs` package which consists of all the common message types which you can use like int, float, string, boolean etc.

You can refer to this link to understand what exactly a ros msg is - http://wiki.ros.org/msg.  Regarding the use of '/' in the include statement, that is because message types in ros are referred to using package resource names meaning  we need to specify the ros package that contains these messages followed by a '/' and the message type.

For example, the file `geometry_msgs/msg/Twist.msg` is commonly referred to as `geometry_msgs/Twist`. Similar is the case for `std_msgs/String` but by writing `#include "std_msgs/String.h`, the string message gets imported in our code like I mentioned earlier.

I suggest reading the documentation given in the links I have provided which can help you in understanding better. Hope this helps you in understanding the meaning of the statement.

---

Originally posted by [Robo_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/90798/robo_guy/) with karma: 115 on 2022-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sajid1122](https://answers.ros.org/users/103351/sajid1122/) on 2022-04-27**:
Thank you so much! You clarified my doubts immensely :)

**Comment by [Robo_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/90798/robo_guy/) on 2022-04-28**:
Welcome, I am glad your doubts have been cleared !!

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-04-28**:
@sajid1122 If Robo_guy has answered your question, please tap that grey checkmark on the left of his answer, that's how you mark it as the correct answer and moves this question to "answered"